# Lambda expression used to replace the nested for-loop, for some reason, does not work

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the following situation, where the lambda expression i used to
replace a working for loop does not work. Have no clue as to why this
fails

```
public class Abc implements IAbc {

    // some fields
    ...
    // field i'm interested in
    @Inject @Any
    private Instance<HandlerInterface> handlers;

    // more members
    ...
    // method i'm interested in
    @Override
    public boolean hasHandler(List<Order> orders) {
        for (Order anOrder : orders) {
            for (HandlerInterface aHandler : handlers) {
                // following canHandler() is implemented by each 
                // handler that implements the HandlerInterface
                if(aHandler.canHandle(anOrder)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        return false;
    }
    // rest of the class content
    .....
}
```

So I was actually trying to replace the above code, within the method,
with Lambdas (to which i'm new). The following was my replacement code

```
public boolean hasHandler(List<Order> orders) {
    return orders.stream().anyMatch(order ->
        Stream.of(handlers).map(Provider::get).anyMatch(handler ->
            handler.canHandle(order)));
}
```

The above lambda expression fails at handler.canHandle with
AmbiguousResolutionException. I can't find out why it works with the
for loop and not with stream. Im sure im doing something wrong here -
but have no clue as to what. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does `Provider::get` return ?

Comment: Why are you inserting a `Provider::get` step that doesn’t exist in the loop code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `Instance<HandlerInterface>` implements `Iterable<HandlerInterface>` (or you wouldn't be able to use it in the enhanced for loop).

This means you can create a `Stream` of the elements of this `Iterable` by calling `StreamSupport.stream(handlers.spliterator(), false);`

So now, your method can be converted to use Streams as follows:

```
public boolean hasHandler(List<Order> orders) {
    return orders.stream()
                 .anyMatch(o -> StreamSupport.stream(handlers.spliterator(), false)
                                             .anyMatch(h -> h.canHandle(o)));
}
```

Note: I removed the `.map(Provider::get)` step, since it has no corresponding step in your original nested loop code.

Comment: I tried this code out and it worked like magic. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases create predicates starting from the innermost condition

First predicate is

```
if(aHandler.canHandle(anOrder)) {
  return true;
}
```

You can write this in lambda as

```
private static Predicate<? super HandlerInterface> p1(Order o) {
    return h -> h.canHandle(o);
}
```

Second(though is not very intuitive) but it is you want to check that for your order any handler that matches predicate `p1`, hence write that as

```
private static Predicate<? super Order> p2(List<HandlerInterface> handlers){
    return o -> handlers.stream().anyMatch(p1(o));
}
```

Hence complete solution becomes

```
orders.stream().anyMatch(p2(handlers));
```

When written inline and removing braces because of single-line predicates you can re-write this as

```
orders.stream().anyMatch(o -> handlers.stream().anyMatch(h -> h.canHandle(o)));
```

Comment: thanks for the response. The handlers.stream() would not work i think as it's not a Collection

Comment: it should be iterable for sure else we can't use it in advanced for loop

Comment: handlers is of type Instance here. It's not a collection. The iterable implementations are injected by CDI at runtime. Im new to using all these so im not sure, but this is my guess